# Writing a netCDF file is extremely slow

Tags: dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to perform a fairly simplistic operation on a dataset involving editing of variable and global attributes on individual netcdf files of 3.5GB each. The files load instantly using `xr.open_dataset` but `dataset.to_netcdf()` is too slow to export after the modifications.
I have tried :

1. Without rechunking and dask invocations.
2. Varying chunk sizes followed by :
3. Using `load()` before `to_netcdf`
4. Using `persist()` or `compute ()` before `to_netcdf`

I am working on a HPC with 10 distributed workers . In all cases, the time taken is more than 15 minutes per file. Is it expected? What else can I try to speed up this process apart from further parallelizing the single file operations using dask delayed?

Answer (score 1):

First a quick note:

> The files load instantly using xr.open_dataset

You *probably* did not actually load the data at this point, only the metadata. Depending on your IO and compression/encoding, it might take considerable CPU and memory to load your data. You should have an idea of how much time you think it ought to take with a single CPU thread.

To answer our question:
netCDF (HDF5) does not play nicely with parallel writing. You will likely find that only one task is writing at a time because of locking, or even that the output data is all going to a single task before writing, regardless of your chunking. Please check your dask dashboard!

May I recommend that you try the zarr format, which works well for parallel applications, because each chunk is in a different file. You still need to make decisions on the correct chunking of your data ([example](https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/ebd2f7a23128c3a3cbf297a5719a986a)).